# Crashed when clicking a link in an Area 51 post

Tags: bug, android-app, area-51, mobile-firefox

The link is the first on in this post: [Why is this question not shown up on its proposal?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27226/why-is-this-question-not-shown-up-on-its-proposal)

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: E2312
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (4059386522)

Comment: Can't reproduce. Area 51 and its "meta" are opened via an external Chrome view (as all external links), not really by the app itself, so this might be an issue with your Chrome/Google app.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I use Firefox

Comment: Google is integral part of android. Maybe the component used by SE app is part of the "core", not of Chrome.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue but I have Chrome installed, and choosing to open the Area 51 link above in SE app automatically opened Chrome instead (even though there is another stock Browser app).